# Check if request.getParameter is null using JPS

Tags: java, jsp, parameters

I don't know how to check if my parameter is null. How?

```
http://localhost:8080/msg?fn=Igor&sn=Jedna&id=2
http://localhost:8080/msg?p_r=null&fn=Igor&sn=Jedna&id=2
```

My code not working:

```
<% if (request.getParameter("p_r").equals("null")) {
    //do stuff with p_r
}
%>
```

AND

```
<% if (request.getParameter("p_r").equals(null)) {
    //do stuff with p_r
}
%>
```

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page

How can I check it?

Comment: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 1):

First, check that param exists.

For example;

```
    <% 
        if(request.getQueryString().contains("p_r=")){
            if (request.getParameter("p_r").equals("null")) {
                out.print("p_r is null.");
             }
        }
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% if (request.getParameter("p_r") == null) {
       //it is null. do null-handling
   }
%>
```